# Is there any way I can convert this BigQuery Query into a BigQuery materialized view?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` so a collegue can generate reports in 'Looker'. I'm unable to do this because of the error:

> Unsupported aggregation function in Materialized view: string_agg.

I have the following BigQuery query, which returns results:

```
SELECT
  a.MovieId,
  STRING_AGG(FullName) AS Actors
FROM 
  `<snip>.movies` a
INNER JOIN 
  `<snip>.movie_actors` b
ON
  a.movieId = b.movieId
GROUP BY a.movieId
```

| Movie | Actors |
| --- | --- |
| 9609891 | Ben Vu,Peter Doan |
| 9766044 | Carley,Kate Barnett |
| 9809930 | Carley |
| 9314772JJ | Luo,C21 Jane, Bob Frank, Julie Amour |

Is it possible that I can use this query to make a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` out of this query?

Because of the lovely `STRING_AGG` function, I feel like this cannot be done.

Or do I have to do this PRIOR to injecting this data into BigQuery (which feels, wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately,  the STRING_AGG function is not [supported](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-create#query_limitations) aggregation yet.
Only the following aggregation functions are currently supported:

- ANY_VALUE (but not over STRUCT)
- APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT
- ARRAY_AGG (but not over ARRAY or STRUCT)
- AVG
- BIT_AND
- BIT_OR
- BIT_XOR
- COUNT
- COUNTIF
- HLL_COUNT.INIT
- LOGICAL_AND
- LOGICAL_OR
- MAX
- MIN
- SUM

As alternative, you can use [ARRAY_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg):

```
WITH my_cte AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT('Android' AS platform, 'ABC 1' AS user_id),
    STRUCT('Android', 'ABC 2'),
    STRUCT('Android', 'ABC'),
    STRUCT('iOS', 'ABC'),
    STRUCT('Web', 'XYZ'),
    STRUCT('Android', 'XYZ'),
    STRUCT('Web', 'RST'),
    STRUCT('iOS', 'RST'),
    STRUCT('iOS', 'RST 1'),
    STRUCT('iOS', 'RST 2')
  ]) AS my_table
)
  SELECT platform
        ,ARRAY_AGG (DISTINCT user_id ORDER BY user_id) AS users
  FROM my_cte
  GROUP BY platform
```

[image]

Another way is to use a temporary table using your query. Then based on this temporary table create a view. But the limitation is the temporary table lives only in the current session.

Comment: wow - this is really helpful! If our `user_id` value (in your dataset above) happens to have `null` values, is it possible to do the same but using `COALESCE` ?

Comment: OH! ok.. getting closer @gotqn ! This works ... `,ARRAY_AGG (DISTINCT user_id IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY user_id) AS users`

Comment: @Pure.Krome Yes, you can use IGNORE NULLS.

Comment: `Materialized views do not support the DISTINCT clause for aggregation function 'array_agg'.`